# How can I open a specific URL every 9 hours in Windows?

Tags: windows, script, scheduled-tasks

I need my computer to open a specific URL every 9 hours, even when the computer is locked (`Win-key + L`).

How can I achieve that?

I must add that I have zero knowledge about scripting for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote:

```
cmd /c start http://example.com
```

in a BAT file and ran a scheduled task for it every 9 hours.